# Isolate LINQ query to type of object in the where clause

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having trouble with this LINQ query,

```
        var names = from name in Name
                    where name.Items.OfType<test.eng>() 
                    select name.Items;
```

But I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to rewrite the query

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

I want to say from the Name object
give me all Name object items that are of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var names = from name in Name
                    where name.Items.GetType().Equals(typeof(test.eng)) 
                    select name.Items;
```

or:

```
 var names = from name in Name
                    where name.Items.GetType().Equals(test.eng) 
                    select name.Items;
```

or:

```
var names = from name in Name
                    where name.Items.GetType() == test.eng 
                    select name.Items;
```

Comment: Thank you, I chose the first one, it was the one that worked for me

Answer (score 7):

You are passing `IEnumerable<test.eng>` to `where` operator. But it requires `bool` value. Instead you can simply project sequence to `Items` and select items of required type:

```
var names = Name.Select(n => n.Items).OfType<test.eng>();
```